# How to add new input field and each input field have a hide element then only show element when input field is click

Tags: javascript

Please help me....with my problem I want to make a system that add new input field and each input field have a hide element only show the element when input field is clicked.
For example I clicked the input1 the element will show and if I clicked the input2 the element will show and  in the input1 the element will hide.

And additional each input field should have a remove button

I don't have a code to show because I don't any idea.

Please help me with this problem.
Thank you and God bless

Comment: If the field is hidden, how would you click on it to show it? You can get started by creating an "Add" button that creates the field and append a "Remove" button beside or near the input field

Comment: How to add new input field using JavaScript I don't have any idea

Comment: Oh ok. If you're doing this to learn then I would recommend you to go through courses from FreeCodeCamp. It would be difficult to get started with code without the basics.

Comment: FYI I have knowledge in programming but not this so difficult...what I want is code how to do it...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//using jquery 

$('.btn').click(function () {
    $('.container').append('<input name="firstname" placeholder="Firt name"/>');
    $('.container').append('<input name="lastname" placeholder="Last name"/>');
});
```

```html
<button class="btn" >Click</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Please, add jQuery library to your code snippet to make it work.